# Escape all HTML except <br>

Tags: php, html, xss, html-entities

I am trying to display comments on a page and am having some trouble.

There are essentially two different types of comments I am trying to handle:

(1) The XSS type.. e.g. `<script type="text/javascript">alert('hi')</script>`. This is handled fairly easily by escaping it before it gets into the database and then running stripslashes and htmlentities on it.

(2) The comment with `<br>` breaks in it. When the data is stored into the database, I am running nl2br on it so the data looks like `hi<br>hello<br><br>etc`. However, when I display this comment, the `<br>`s do not turn into page breaks like I want them to.

Any idea what to do? I should note that turning off htmlentities fixes the second type, but the first type then is executed as pure html and displays an alert dialog.

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Have you tried strip_tags? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method: Replace `<br>` with a placeholder, like `\n`.  Then do htmlentities to clean up html code.  Finally, replace `\n` back with `<br>` to recover the line breaks.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to remove unwanted tags you can try `strip_tags`. It supports `allowable_tags` so you can specify any tags that you don't want to be stripped. A sample from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
// Allow <p> and <a>
// you can add <br> if you want it not stripped
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

So after you've converted all `\n` to be line breaks you dont have to worry about it being stripped. May not be what you want but hope it gives an idea.

Comment: yes, but it actually tear apart <script> tag for example, maybe you just want to be escaped instead deleted ...&gt;script&lt; and for the rest to be normal